# How to import file of imports to Angular app module

Tags: javascript, angular

I have multiple imports on app module and I want to put them in a different file and import them to app module.
For example:

```
import { MatButtonModule } from "@angular/material/button";
import { MatInputModule } from "@angular/material/input";
import { MatMenuModule } from "@angular/material/menu";
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
```

Put all Material imports on a different file and import it to app module.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate module (or multiple, designated for specific things, e.g. one for angular material) that imports and exports (important) all the single modules and then import that module in you app module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatInputModule } from "@angular/material/input";
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    MatButtonModule, 
    MatInputModule,
    ...
  ],
  exports: [ 
    MatButtonModule, 
    MatInputModule,
    ... 
  ],
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

Than in the app module

```
import { MaterialModule} from '<path>';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    MaterialModule
  ],
})
export class AppModule{ }
```

Note:
If you have submodules, those need to import the MaterialModule too if they need certain components contained.